# System.import promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I've stumbled upon some snippets [similar to this one](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#browser-support):

```
  System.import('core-js').then( function() {
    System.import('polymer/mutationobservers').then( function() {
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    })
  });
```

Is it a substitution for callback hell - a promise hell? Can sequential `System.import`s be flattened to make use of promise chaining, or there may be problems with that?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm just citing existing code piece, but yes, these 3 modules depend on each other. The first two are polyfill libraries, it is dev's choice if they are required.

Comment: @torazaburo He linked to the location the code is from. It explicitly says that you have to load those if you want IE9 support, but that they are optional. The snippet is directly from the Aurelia website. They do depend on eachother by virtue of being polyfills and relying on globals being present.

Comment: @estus - promises are unfortunately widely misunderstood, so yes you'll come across code like this quite a bit.  That being said, there are legitimate ways to avoid callback hell - and the same people who created mountains of callbacks likely have no problem creating mountains of promises.

Comment: @aaaaaa It was confusing to see that in decent framework's documentation (and I consider Aurelia a decent one), so made me wonder if there was some reason behind that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend chaining instead, e.g.

```
System.import('core-js')
    .then(function(){
        return System.import('polymer/mutationobservers');
    })
    .then(function(){
        return System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    });
```

When you `return` a promise from a `then`, it will wait for that to resolve before executing the next `then`, so in this case `mutationobservers` must load before `aurelia-bootstrapper`.

Answer (score 3):

Since System.import returns a promise, use a group of promises. I find it quite a bit more straight forward than chaining.

```
Promise.all([
    System.import('core-js'),
    System.import('polymer/mutationobservers'),
    System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper')
]).then(function(modules) {
    var corejs = modules.shift(),
        mutationobservers = modules.shift(),
        aureliaBootstrapper = modules.shift()
    ;

    // You code goes here.
});
```

Comment: I guess that the problem here is that the first two are polyfill libraries. But other than that, yes, it would be a good use case for `Promise.all`.

Comment: Using es6 destructuring, you can avoid having to use `modules.shift()` to assign the module variables, e.g. ``.then(([corejs, mutationobservers, aureliaBootstrapper]) => { // your code ... ``

Answer (score 2):

I prefer async/await in this situation however you need to be inside an async function which might not always work for import statements

```
function async doStuff () {
    await System.import('core-js');
    await System.import('polymer/mutationobservers');
    await System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    console.log('everything done!!!');
}
```